# How many different ships or class types exist in the Star Trek universe to bear the name Sarajevo?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

In the Enterprise episode Daedalus **(4x10)** and the DS9 episode In Purgatory's Shadow **(5x14)** the Sarajevo is mentioned as a ship.

In ENT it is both a ship class and the ship that transported Danica and Emory Erickson to Earth.

In DS9 it is mentioned as lost, and later found in the Gamma quadrant.

**Are there any other ships that bear the same name or ship type in the periods from ENT to DS9?**

Answer (score 2):

**It doesn't look like it**.

After searching all of the related pages on [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org), I could find only two ships with that name, and one class.

See

- [Sarajevo-type](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarajevo_type)
- [Sarajevo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarajevo)
- [USS Sarajevo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Sarajevo)

As for the type of class that the USS Sarajevo is (Istanbul), I could only find the [*USS Constantinople*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Constantinople).